# Different behaviour when wrapping in a method : scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

There're two kinds of my code, and it worked:

One uses `flatten` directly

```
val list = List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4))
println(list.flatten)
```

The other use a method

```
val list = List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4))
println(flatten(list))

def flatten(list: List[Any]): List[Any] = {
        list.flatten//this is the line 28
}
```

And there comes an error:

```
Error:(28, 14) No implicit view available from Any => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B].
        list.flatten

Error:(28, 14) not enough arguments for method flatten: (implicit asTraversable: Any => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B])List[B].
Unspecified value parameter asTraversable.
        list.flatten
```

Why and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the method you want.

```
def flatten[A](list: List[List[A]]): List[A] = {
  list.flatten
}
```

The generic `A` (or whatever name you want to give it) is different from type `Any`.  The generic means "some type that is consistent within the `List`" while `Any` means "I don't know anything about any of the elements within the `List`".

So a `List[Any]` can't be flattened because the compiler doesn't know anything about the contents of the list. A `List[List[Any]]` can be flattened but the result is a `List[Any]` which isn't as useful as `List[A]` because the compiler will have attached a meaning to `A` (`Int`, `Char`, `String`, ....) and that's what you'll get back (`List[Int]`, `List[Char]`, `List[String]`, ....).